# How to find if a file recursively in directory A is also present recursively in directory B in bash

Tags: bash

Let's have following simple example

```
A
|-abc.txt
|-soijwerow.txt
|-AA
   |-oiwejr.pdf
   |-AAA
      |-xyz.txt


B
|-xyz.txt
|-sor233w.txt
|-AA
   |-o777iwejr.pdf
   |-AAA
      |-abc.txt
```

the output should report abc.txt and xyz.txt (with all corresponding paths, where files with same name found)

it should ignore similiar directory names

it should also be case sensitive.

EDIT : It should ignore the file content (Only filename should be a check, not the file content). It should also ignore the corresponding file paths. ( File can be at any depth in the particular directory )

I have tried `diff -sqr A B`

but that is not going recursively. (only childs are shown) Plus , it also shows directory results.

Comment: What do you mean by *recursively in directory A* ? Should the paths be the same? Should the contents of the files be same regardless of the path? Is it just the filenames you're looking at? Your question is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a dir2tree=()
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'
do
    dir2tree+=("$REPLY")
done< <(find dir2 -type f -print0)

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0'
do
    echo -e "----->for $REPLY in dir2 tree"
    for filepath in "${dir2tree[@]}"
    do
        egrep "$(sed -r 's@^.*/(.*)$@\1@g' <<< "$REPLY")$" <<< "$filepath" 1> /dev/null && echo -e "\t$filepath"
    done
done< <(find dir1 -type f -print0)
```

Asumming there are no funny chars in filename messing with regex, I've created a temp dir struct with randomd names, here is the dir structure and output:

```
$ls -R dir1
dir1:
abc.txt  dir4

dir1/dir4:
xyz.txt
~/temp$ ls -R dir2
dir2:
dir3  xyz.txt

dir2/dir3:
tempdir

dir2/dir3/tempdir:
abc.txt
~/temp$ ./script.bash 
----->for dir1/abc.txt in dir2 tree
    dir2/dir3/tempdir/abc.txt
----->for dir1/dir4/xyz.txt in dir2 tree
    dir2/xyz.txt
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to list duplicate file names with their full paths.

One crude way of doing this, is to store a hash of basenames to full paths and then simply look for duplicates in this hash.

You do something like this: (untested)

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR_A=/path/to/dir1
DIR_B=/path/to/dir2

# Create an associate array aka hash

declare -A file_list
# Find and store files from $DIR_A
for file in $(find $DIR_A -type f -print)
do
  file_list[$(basename $file)]=$file
done

# Look for duplicates in $DIR_B
for file in $(find $DIR_B -type -f -print)
do
  base_name=$(basename $file)
  if [[ ${file_list[${base_name}] ]]; then
    echo "Duplicate found for ${base_name} :"
    echo file_name[${base_name}]
    echo ${file}
  fi
done
```

There are probably a few edge cases this doesn't handle yet, for example it doesn't detect duplicates inside directory A itself, I'll improve it when I get time later in the day.